# .htaccess file for magento in subdirectory

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

We are finding it difficult to remove the redirection of my /admin to /index.php/admin, which is not allowing us to access the admin panel, at every url that should start with /admin/ gets redirected to /index.php/admin/ and it displays `No input file specified.` and when i remove index.php from the url it works fine.

My .htaccess file looks like this

```
DirectoryIndex /new/magento-k/index.php

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /mysubdirectory/


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index.php/admin.*$
RewriteRule ^/index.php/admin(.*) /admin$1 [R]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]


RewriteRule ^/index.php/(admin|user)($|/) - [L]

Options -MultiViews
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this into your .htaccess file

```
RewriteRule .* /index.php [L]
```

and remove the other index.php rule:

```
RewriteRule ^/index.php/(admin|user)($|/) - [L]
```

Also make sure to clear cache of Magento and your browser.